# border-color:transparent is not working in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, colors, border, internet-explorer-6

`style="border:solid 1px transparent"` is not working in IE6. Instead it shows a black border.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: My recommendation is to give up supporting IE6 unless you're being paid a very good bonus for it. There's a lot of things which IE6 doesn't support, including this, and you're going to spend a lot of time fighting with it. As a web designer, if they ask you to support IE6, you should at least double your price.

Comment: @Spudley: I totally agree with you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE6 does not support a `border` that is `transparent`.

With a quick search, I found this workaround:

http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/emulating-border-color-transparent-in-internet-explorer-6/

> To
>   put it to work with IE6, we will
>   create another rule, that is visible
>   only in version 6 (the *html hack)
>   with just two lines of code:
>
> ```
> *html .testDiv { 
>     border-color: pink;
>     filter: chroma(color=pink);
> }
> ```
>
> … And voila! The ugly black border
>   around .testDiv magically disappears.
>
> The final things you should have in
>   mind before using this trick is the
>   color (both border and chroma color)
>   in the hack. Make sure you apply a
>   border-color (and respectively use it
>   in the chroma filter) that is not used
>   in that div, as the chroma filter
>   displays a certain color of the object
>   and its content as transparent, i.e.
>   if the border-color in the hack is
>   orange, and the text in your element
>   is orange as well, it will disappear
>   when the orange chroma filter is
>   applied.

Comment: @Naveed Butt: Are you sure? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532982(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes it worked but when filter is applied, my letters inside the div where the border was applied gets distorted. What can be the reason?

Comment: I'll take a look. What colour text/border/chroma are you using?

Comment: color of the text - #919191, border-color - #898989, chroma(color=#898989)

Comment: I'm not at my computer with an IE6 virtual machine at the moment, so I'm using http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ to test it. Testing with http://fiddle.jshell.net/SgJ4Z/show/light/ (with chroma) vs http://fiddle.jshell.net/SgJ4Z/1/show/light/ (without chroma), I can't see any difference in the text. I can only assume you're suffering from the usual "horrible text syndrome" you get whenever you apply a `filter` and you're using some kind of font smoothing on setting on your computer (netrender isn't using this). I don't think you can fix it without splitting the border and text into two elements.

Comment: In that class, I have also set width property. When I removed the width property the distortion disappeared. But I can't remove the width property. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: In my testing, you needed to apply a width (*or other property providing hasLayout*) to make the border transparent in IE6. Are you sure the border was *still transparent* when you removed the width property?

Comment: @ thirtydot: Yes, you are right. The border is not transparent when the width is removed

Comment: I don't think there is a way to have the transparent border working in IE without splitting the border and text into two separate elements. How many of the users of your site are going to be using IE6? If it's only [the usual minority](http://ie6countdown.com/), you should probably just leave it and put up with the poor quality text.

Comment: @ thirtydot: I think its better not to waste time for this IE6 issue :)