# SASS - how to change the code if the browser is IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm studing SASS and using twitter bootstrap

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

The twitter bootstrap is using Less, but i found a translation for SASS.

For the .btn there is

```
  *border: 0; // Remove the border to prevent IE7's black border on input:focus
```

but the border is still there , if you see the twitter bootstrap buttons they are okay under IE . How they make that ?

Comment: Could you link the SASS port you are using?

Comment: If you're asking about the asterisk before the property name, it's called a CSS “star-hack” for IE (see “[What does a star-preceded property mean in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1667560/247441)”).

Answer (score 0):

If you change the border from 1px to 0px, you must increase the line-height by 2px.

```
.btn{
  *line-height: 20px;
 }
```

You need to be more precise:

- "i found a translation for SASS." which one?
- "... buttons they are okay under IE" which IE?

If you try to have transparent border on IE6 this may help: [IE6 Issue - border-color:transparent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714356/ie6-issue-border-colortransparent-not-working)

Comment: I just want to hide the border for IE users because is very dark.. So i'm using IE 8 and i know that * css hack work to IE 7 and below

Comment: @MarianPetrov have your tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714356/ie6-issue-border-colortransparent-not-working

Comment: I will try it , now i'm using border:0px/9; but this work to IE 10 but the button are fine in IE 9 so i want to hide it from ie 8 and below